# How to find the height of the left and right subtree in C#

Tags: c#, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, subtree

How to find the subtree height both left and right, I have used this code in the following link
[C# BST](http://snipd.net/binary-search-trees-bsts-in-c)

Any help would be appreciated.

Kind Regards

Comment: what is *height* of a binary tree? max height? min height?

Comment: this is to check if it is height balanced or not. as I am new to coding, I have no idea how to frame this. I need to know the max height of the left sub tree and max height of the right subtree

Comment: was looking for that function to find the height using the source above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if it's a correct implementation of BST, then they should be balanced.

But to test it, here is an easy recursive implementation.

```
public int TreeDepth( TreeNode<T> tree, int depth = 0 )
{
    int leftDepth = tree.Left != null 
        ? TreeDepth( tree.Left, depth + 1 ) 
        : depth;
    int rightDepth = tree.Right != null 
        ? TreeDepth( tree.Right, depth + 1 ) 
        : depth;
    return leftDepth >= rightDepth 
        ? leftDepth 
        : rightDepth;
}
```

Comment: It is implemented right, I have checked testing the code. I am wondering how to call TreeDepth and what parameters to pass. Thank you for the help @Kaerber

Comment: You just pass it a tree you want to measure, like that: var depth = TreeDepth( root );